# Copy cell contents from one Google Worksheet to another

Tags: google-sheets

I hope you can help me! I'd like to copy cell contents from one worksheet to another with

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheetByName("master");
var destination = ss.getSheetByName("ppg");

var range = source.getRange("A2:AR"); 

range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 4,6,4,6);
}
```

Contents are copied, but the formulas are gone?! Any idea how to fix that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
var rangeTo = destination.getRange(4,6)
range.copyTo(rangeTo);
```

As [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) says:

> **copyTo(destination, options)**
>
> Copies the data from a range of cells to another range of cells. By
>   default both the values and formatting are copied, but this can be
>   overridden using advanced arguments.

---

command `copyValuesToRange` will copy values (contents) only